# Matplotlib: Line plot point not aligned with X values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am having a problem line plots point not aligned with x values as shown in the picture
[image]

```html
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dataframe.index,dataframe['SRC_RESNUM']['Column_name'], color="cornflowerblue", marker="o")
ax.set_xlabel("Trades",fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Records Mailed",color="black",fontsize=14)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 10]
plt.xticks(range(0,len(dataframe.index)),dataframe.index,rotation='vertical')
#plt.xticks(range(10))
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(dataframe.index,dataframe['RESP_RESPONSEFLAG']['Column_name'],color="gold",marker="o")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 10]
ax2.set_ylabel("Responses",color="black",fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(range(0,len(dataframe.index)),dataframe.index,rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does the dataframe and it's index look like?  What is the variable `column`.

Comment: This is my index
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64', name='CREDIT_ALL15')
my column is int